# Docker MariaDB не могу примонтировать папку с данными

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Вот ошибка

```
db_1          | 2019-01-22 19:01:53 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.3.12-MariaDB-1:10.3.12+maria~bionic) starting as process 1 ...
db_1          | 2019-01-22 19:01:53 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
db_1          | 2019-01-22 19:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
db_1          | 2019-01-22 19:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
db_1          | 2019-01-22 19:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
db_1          | 2019-01-22 19:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
db_1          | 2019-01-22 19:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
db_1          | 2019-01-22 19:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
db_1          | 2019-01-22 19:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 256M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
db_1          | 2019-01-22 19:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db_1          | 2019-01-22 19:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
db_1          | 2019-01-22 19:01:53 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Failed to set O_DIRECT on file./ibdata1; OPEN: Invalid argument, continuing anyway. O_DIRECT is known to result in 'Invalid argument' on Linux on tmpfs, see MySQL Bug#26662.
db_1          | 2019-01-22 19:01:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Header page consists of zero bytes in datafile: ./ibdata1, Space ID:0, Flags: 0. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
db_1          | 2019-01-22 19:01:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Corrupted page [page id: space=0, page number=0] of datafile './ibdata1' could not be found in the doublewrite buffer.
db_1          | 2019-01-22 19:01:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Data structure corruption
db_1          | 2019-01-22 19:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
db_1          | 2019-01-22 19:01:53 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
db_1          | 2019-01-22 19:01:53 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
db_1          | 2019-01-22 19:01:53 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
db_1          | 2019-01-22 19:01:53 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
db_1          | 2019-01-22 19:01:53 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
db_1          | 2019-01-22 19:01:53 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    build: ./db
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123
    volumes:
      - ./databases:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

Я изпользую Docker toolbox Windows
Версия Docker 18.03.0-ce 
Версия Docker compose  1.20.1
ОС Windows 10 1809

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Какова цель создания:

```
volumes:
      - ./databases:/var/lib/mysql
```

Если вам нужно сохранять базу данных при перезапуске контейнера, то следует использовать такую конструкцию:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  db:
    build: ./db
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123
    volumes:
      - database:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
volumes:
   database:
```

Таким образом содержимое /var/lib/mysql будет сохраняться в /var/lib/docker/volumes